# Can't install bundler using gem

Tags: macos, ruby

I'm trying to install [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) on my Mac which is running OS X El Capitan Public Beta 6 (15A278b).

I try `sudo gem install bundler` but I get the following error back

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno:EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle

Comment: It seems as if you need to disable rootless. Since you are using beta software the procedure may change but you can try `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0";sudo reboot`.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to disable rootless my going into Recovery HD and turning it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

<sup>Source: [Package is incompatible with this version of OS X](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/)</sup>

Comment: Fighting Apple's security practices by disabling it wholesale is both a losing battle and counter-productive. Bundler recommends `-n /usr/local/bin` gem installs now, as do most other active ruby projects.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, use a newer version of bundler - disabling a core security feature of the operating system is a Bad Idea and will leave your machine vulnerable.

Comment: You can re-enable SIP once installation is complete. SIP was non-existent on prior versions of OS X so you're not creating a huge security hole.

Answer (score 2):

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin bundler

Answer (score 2):

Use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) (or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) if you prefer, I don't). If you ever have to use `sudo` while installing/upgrading a gem then you're walking towards trouble, if not already there.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not ever disable SIP so here's another way to get the bundler gem installed without needing to mess with restricted file permissions and reboot twice.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/rubygems
sudo chown user:group /usr/local/bin/rubygems
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rubygems/
gem install bundler
```

Now, you'll probably want to export the [GEM_HOME variable in a shell dot file or make a configuration file for gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/333519/475228). You'll certainly need to change the user and group for the `chown` command to be your user.

If this doesn't meet your needs, [setting up a ruby environment management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223202/5472) tool is also [+1 in my book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209256/how-to-install-ruby-gems-without-sudo).