# How to install ruby gems without sudo

Tags: terminal, install, sudo, ruby

I want to install a Ruby Gem to my computer, but since I don't have an administrator account I can't use `sudo`. How do I install a Gem without `sudo`, and what (if any) privileges do I loose? This is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728498/what-privileges-do-i-lose-when-i-install-cocoapods-without-sudo) I asked on Stack Overflow.

### Update:

I installed RVM, but I got these two errors:

```
WARNING: your RVM loading script `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` is deprecated
and causes you to have `umask g+w` set in your shell,
run `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles` again to fix your scripts.
```

And

```
WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
to do that add the following line to '/Users/CalebKleveter/.bash_profile':

  source ~/.profile
```

I ran `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`, but I got the same errors again. Any suggestions on what to do? And what does the second error message want me to do?

### Update 2:

I tried gem install cocoapods and I got the error in my other post, then I tried rvm gem install cocoapods and I got "Please note that rvm gem ... was removed, try gem install cocoapods or rvm all do gem install cocoapods instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )" so I tried rvm all do gem install cocoapods and it just started a new command prompt, that is what is supposed to happen, right?

Comment: I actually use `rvm`. It installs ruby into your home folder, so you don't need `sudo`. It works fine for me. Try that, and if it works I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @IronCraftMan, if you look at the link you will notice I tried to install RVM, but it didn't work. "The other solution of installing RVM I looked into, but I had trouble installing it. (Maybe because I'm not an admin?)", Can you go over how to install RVM?

Comment: By "some errors again" do you meant the same ones as before?

Comment: @IronCraftMan, Yes.

Comment: can you run `gem install (yourgem) `

Comment: @IronCraftMan, I tried `gem install cocoapods` and I got the error in my other post, then I tried `rvm gem install cocoapods` and I got "Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem install cocoapods` or `rvm all do gem install cocoapods` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )" so I tried `rvm all do gem install cocoapods` and it just started a new command prompt, that is what is supposed to happen, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29919/discussion-between-caleb-kleveter-and-ironcraftman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVM:

From the rvm.io homepage, I used: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` . This worked fine for me, no admin permissions needed.

Comment: Sorry about my delay. I added an update to my post.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install a Ruby Gem to my computer, but since I don't have an administrator account I can't use `sudo`. How do I install a Gem without `sudo`, and what (if any) privileges do I loose?

Yes, use the `--user-install` flag, which will install gems into your local directory.

```
gem install jekyll --user-install
```

This will make them only accessible to you, not to other users on the machine.  You may need to add the `bin` directory into your `PATH`; if so, `gem install` will tell you.